# Avoid output via negative index for numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array A such as:

```
[[    0.   482.  1900.   961.   579.    56.]
 [    0.   530.  1906.   914.   584.    44.]
 [   43.     0.  1932.   948.   556.    51.]
 [    0.   482.  1917.   946.   581.    52.]
 [    0.   520.  1935.   878.   589.    55.]]
```

I am getting the element I need to filter like this:

```
C = array([-1, -1, -1,  1,  2], dtype=int64)
R = array([[-2, -5],
       [-1, -5],
       [ 0, -4],
       [ 1, -3],
       [ 2, -2],
       [ 3, -1]])
```

Extracting this way: `A[R.T, C]`

Issue: Negative indexing is giving me trouble. I would like to get NaN for the entries with either R or C or both <0. Is this possible?

Comment: There is something wrong with values in *R* array (actually, *-6* is the source of the problem).
To state precisely what is wrong, please provide the output you are getting so far. Please provide also the expected output.

Comment: You are correct as far as -6 is concerned. Have modifed that.

Comment: There's still something wrong: `A[R.T, C]` won't evaluate because of the shape mismatch. I guess either C has to have 6 elements or R has to have 5 rows. Then it will evaluate.

Comment: @user13744439, no feedback? Have you resolved your issue? I'm interested...

Answer (score -1):

As an exercise I assume your R or C arrays are of a wrong shape (because for your data `A[R.T, C]` returns a shape mismatch error), so I choose to remove one row from R:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(30).reshape(5, 6)
C = np.array([-1, -1, -1,  1,  2], dtype=np.int64)
R = np.array([[-2, -5],
       [ 0, -4],
       [ 1, -3],
       [ 2, -2],
       [ 3, -1]])
```

and then `A[R.T, C]` evaluates to:

```
array([[23,  5, 11, 13, 20],
       [ 5, 11, 17, 19, 26]])
```

Now I assume you're for some reason trying to replace all values that would otherwise be supplied by a negative index, with the NaN value. That leads me to an expected result of:

```
array([[nan, nan, nan, 13., 20.],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

Is that a correct expectation??

If so, I'd suggest to add a row and a column consisting of NaN values to A and replace all negative indexes with -1 which will do the trick:

```
nan_row = np.full((1, 6), np.NAN)
nan_col = np.full((6, 1), np.NAN)
A = np.r_[A, nan_row]
A = np.c_[A, nan_col]
R[R<0] = -1
C[C<0] = -1
```

`A[R.T, C]` now returns the expected array:

```
array([[nan, nan, nan, 13., 20.],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```